# How to increment a val in "for loop" in Kotlin when a statement is true

Tags: loops, for-loop, kotlin, increment

In java we can increment "i' in for loop when a condition is true

for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
if(condition)
i++
}

If I do the increment in Kotlin, it shows that "val cannot be changed".

for(i in x){
if(condition)
i++
}

How can we increment in Kotlin?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Kotlin provides enough constructs to avoid the whole need for mutable data structures. If you need to do it this way there probably is a better way

Answer (score 6):

Try using a while loop. "Note that a for loop always implicitly declares a new read-only variable." The i is read-only.

```kotlin
var x = 0
while (x < 10) {
    if (condition) x++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **while** instead of **for** and increment it manually.

Comment: var degree = 0; while (degree < 360) { degree *= 5

        }